# Making java code usable from other programming/scripting language

Tags: java, python

We are "extending" a product developed by a third party and working with them on that. There's a small problem though. They have some functions (written in java) that they use in their Android mobile app and we need to use these functions in our development too. The other side is not too sure on what is the best way to share the functions/code. Ultimately we need to use those functions in one of our python scripts. Any suggestions on how this should be done? Should we ask them for a java library; a .jar file or something?

I am not sure if I have explained the question clearly but we never had to do any such integration before and so this is new to us and hence the doubts. thanks

Comment: Create an service / API. Perhaps [something like this](https://javaee.github.io/metro/).

Comment: thanks. I did think about webservice for a moment but it looked a bit of an overkill having another service just to do that. In future those functions might change and if we rewrote that in other language, we will have to constantly update it as the other side changes it.

Comment: But ya there is a definite advantage of using a web service. We no longer have to worry from where we call the service - be it php, c++, python etc

Comment: I am surprised at the downvotes. No wonder I have seen many people on other forums who dread asking questions on "anything stack" and keep away. If all are experts in every programming language, why do we need a stack this and stack that? Or why not rename this to expertexchange where only experts ask and experts answer?

Comment: At least 2 people have just proved exactly what many other forums are discussing , that is  "before you have any answer(or even a hint) get ready for the gods of programming to downvote you by the dozens" It's too diffcult for these supreme beings to write a one line answer saying "You can do this" but instead the hands miraculously moves towards the downvote button. lol... none of the junior programmers in my company use stackxxx anymore - I am not surprised now ... it is because people like those who downvoted this question

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one of the reasons for downvote I can see is your problem is specific to your own needs. SE strives to be a **repository of good questions/answers** that can benefit people of the future who will try to find an answer. 2nd reason for downvote I can see is lack of research. When you post a question on SE - you have to do prior research. You mentioned you thought about creating an API. That was the right direction to think in. If you need to reuse code between multiple apps - API / service is the way to go. You should have looked into that to see if is what you need.

Comment: The way it is right now your question sounds very general, or broad. Your questions is kind of like a far away younger sibling of [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35939/how-do-web-apis-work), which was closed as "too broad". To ask questions on SE questions you have to be more specific. It is these strict rules that make SE of a much better quality then other q/a sites and forums. Don't get discouraged. Grow a thick skin. And welcome to Stack Exchange.

Comment: Please read [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#answer-9961). The important part in bold is: "the up/down vote system is the core of how we get the "good stuff" up and the "bad stuff" down. It is not designed to be a personal attack against the users in question."

Comment: Research told me that some options would be libraries or frameworks like Jpype, Py4j etc but we never dealt with such a case before and have no prior experience 'mating' these 2 very different beasts. Moreover a quick try did make at least couple of them feel clunky and cumbersome.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried writing snippets to call a Hello World java program .. and that's when I thought that a pointer from someone who has done this before would be great and I'd be researching the correct place instead of all over the web only to later find that it wasn't really a great way after all. My mistake was in assuming that there is an accepted and clean way to achieve this. Perhaps a one liner like "check out this framework ... or hey a Web service should be fine"

Comment: My friend, you misunderstand what this website is for, and that's OK - there is a learning curve to this website. I found a post that explains exactly why you've been downvoted: [please read it here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start). Also, you said `I should have mentioned...` yes, you should have and you can edit your question and mention everything that you have to. And `check out this framework` is asking for an outside resource, which is one of the reasons why questions are being downvoted and closed.

Comment: Thanks Alex, yes I could have phrased that question in a better way ... probably add a bit of what I had tried already. I know of no native way of making calls or using the java stuff and hence the use of the word "framework" :)

Comment: Also, please check out [this blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) on how to ask good questions, and tell your junior programmers to read it as well.

Comment: I have to ask whether you are aware of [Jython](http://www.jython.org/)?  Calling Java code from Python scripts in Jython is stupid simple.

Comment: Jython and Py4j are in the "to try" list. But thanks for mentioning Jython; every affirmation decreases the chances of going off the tangent :)

Comment: @M.M I've been using Jython for years and I have found it to be pretty solid.  The downside is that it's not an terribly active effort and I'm not sure when if ever Python 3 will be implemented.  At this point, though, 2.7 seems to be the standard and hey, no GIL.  That's a bonus.

Comment: Thanks JimmyJames, I'll try Jython. I am not too worried about long term because in a few months to come, I am gona rewrite their stuff.